# powershell get-aduser query with two or more name variables

Tags: powershell

I'm tryin to get a powershell query with two displaynames in it. It works fine with one displayname.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "displayName -like '**'" -SearchBase "OU= ,OU= ,OU= AG,DC= ,DC=" -Properties *  | select-object mail | sort-object
```

How can i insert more displayname variables to the code?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *two displaynames*? Are you looking for two different accounts? If that's the case you could use `-or` to combine two conditions.

Comment: BTW: Instead of `-Properties *` you should use `-Properties mail` if you don't need all attributes from your AD objects. That's less stress for your AD.

Comment: i need it like "displaynames -like 'david' -and 'steven' -and 'stephan'

Comment: So there is someone in your AD with the Name "David Steven Stephan"? ... really?  BTW: This should be in your question. Please update it with all relevant information. The more verbose you are the better we can help.

Comment: Try the solution Daniel posted.

Comment: no :-) for example i wan't all employees with david in its name and steven

Comment: sorry it was my fault. i had a mistake in thinking :-)

Comment: Again ... this is ambiguous. Do you want all eployees with David in their name and all employees with Steven in there name? Then you need to use `-or`. If you're looking for all employees with David and Steven in their name you need `-and`.  ... try Daniels suggestion please!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use OR in the filter

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -like '*user1*' -or DisplayName -like '*user2*'" -SearchBase "OU= ,OU= ,OU= AG,DC= ,DC=" -Properties Mail  | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Mail | Sort-Object
```

Using LDAP Filter you can do like this (using `|` as OR)

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(|(cn=*user1*)(cn=*user2*))" -SearchBase "OU= ,OU= ,OU= AG,DC= ,DC=" -Properties Mail  | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Mail | Sort-Object
```

Comment: i need the -and

Comment: @chkdsk No you really need `-or`. If you use `-and`, you will be seaching for a user that has **all** of the possible displaynames, so you'll most likely find nothing then..